# How to stop retina.js if iPhone dected

Tags: javascript, jquery, retina-display, retina.js

I've got my jquery slideshows looking sharp with retina displays thanks to [retina.js](http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/), but I only want retina.js to function for non-iPhone retina devices. (iPads and laptops). So, I just need a bit of code to tell retina/js to not function if an iPhone is detected.

Can anyone suggest some code? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're detecting if the user is on an iPhone but simply loading only `retina.js` when you deem appropriate should be all you need to do

```
if (!browser.iphone) $.getScript("path/to/retina.js");
```

Where `browser.iphone` is your browser detection code

Comment: Retina.js does a fine job of detecting all things retina, but I want it to make an exception for retina iPhones and not run if one is detected.

Comment: @ian_6500 as far as I can tell reading [the source](https://github.com/imulus/retinajs/blob/master/src/retina.js) you either need to not load it if you don't need it or mod the source to not call `Retina.init()`. Loading the script conditionally through javascript is the simplest solution